# Jenkins lock by label

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

## What I'm trying to achieve

- I have `jobA` that needs 1 executor on one machine.
- I have `jobB` that needs 2 executors on the same machine and 1 executor on X machines.
- I want them to be able to use the same machines (not at the same time though) -> They currently use different machines.
- All of their tasks use 100% CPU. So, no two builds can concurrently exist on the same machine.

## How I'm tackling the problem

- Because `jobB` requires at least 2 executors on a single node and `jobA` requires 1, I need to change the numbers of executors to have 2 per node.
- There should be a lock mechanism so that if `jobA` or `jobB` build runs on a node, no `jobA` nor `jobB` build can start on it.

## What I've done

I changed the number of executors on my machines from 1 to 2.

#### Solution 1: Locking the resource

In `jobA`'s pipeline, I have:

```
node('windows-agent-label') {
    lock("${env.NODE_NAME}-exclusive") {
        //...
    }
}
```

Running the job (1st time) gives me:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on build1 in J:\jenkins\workspace\jobA
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] lock
Trying to acquire lock on [build1-exclusive]
Resource [build1-exclusive] did not exist. Created.
Lock acquired on [build1-exclusive]
```

And the 2nd time (while the first one is still building):

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on build1 in J:\jenkins\workspace\jobA@2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] lock
Trying to acquire lock on [build1-exclusive]
Found 0 available resource(s). Waiting for correct amount: 1.
[build1-exclusive] is locked, waiting...
```

It works! The second build is blocked until the first one releases the lock. However, **the second one is already dispatched to the node and uses an executor slot**. Really not nice! If I move the `lock()` directive outside of the `node()` one, I don't have the `env.NODE_NAME` yet, so the lock cannot work.

Apparently, there's another way...

#### Solution 2: Locking by requesting a label

I have a label named `windows-agent-label` which contains 2 nodes: `build1` and `build2`.

In `jobA`'s pipeline, I have:

```
lock(label: 'windows-agent-label', quantity: 1) {
    node('windows-agent-label') {
        //...
    }
}
```

Running the job gives me:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] lock
Trying to acquire lock on [Label: windows-agent-label, Quantity: 1]
Found 0 available resource(s). Waiting for correct amount: 1.
[Label: windows-agent-label, Quantity: 1] is locked, waiting...
```

**Absolutely nothing is running** on `build1`.

All of my `/lockable-resources/` are `FREE`.

## Questions

- Why cannot it find an available resource? Am I misusing it?
- I am in the right direction?

Comment: Thank you! The quantity 1 is what was missing from the documentation of the plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The solution

In the `lock` documentation, there's a missing (undocumented) parameter: `variable`. When used with `label`, it stores into an `env` variable the name of the acquired lock.

Missing here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources

Visible there: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40997

```
lock(label: 'windows-agent-label', quantity: 1, variable: 'LOCK_NAME') {
    node(env.LOCK_NAME - '-exclusive') {
        //...
    }
}
```

So, this requests a lock from all the ones that are under a certain label. They are always formed (by choice) as `${NODE_NAME}-exclusive`. If I can't get a lock on resource, that means they're all used up. If I get one, that means `NODE_NAME` (could be `build1`, `build2`, ...) is available. So, I go to the given node.

Comment: Warning: if a node is offline, it will get the lock, then wait on the node forever (well, until it gets online).