# Jenkins global lock - Using 2 Jenkins Masters with a common Jenkins agent

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, locking, cicd

I would like to use 2  jenkins masters, with common (generic) jenkins agent - with a locking mechanism.

Assume I have 2 jenkins jobs `RESOURCE-INTENSE-JOB` and `LOW-RESOURCES-JOB`, jenkins masters `MASTER-1` and `MASTER-2` and jenkins agent node `NODE-1` that they share.

Also the agents are selected to be executed on by label `generic` for example.

`NODE-1` can run any of the jobs, but it can (and should) run `LOW-RESOURCES-JOB` simultaneously, but only one `RESOURCE-INTENSE-JOB` at a time, and **ONLY IT**. (no other job can be executed alongside the resource intense job).

As stated in the jenkins official docs `https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/scaling/architecting-for-scale/#define-a-policy-to-share-agent-machines`:

'''
As mentioned previously, agents should be interchangeable and standardized in order to make them sharable and to optimize resource usage. Agents should not be customized for a particular set of jobs, nor for a particular team...

Note that the restriction has to be replicated in every single job to be tied and that the **agent won’t be protected from being used by other teams**

'''

I would like to know if there is a way to protect the agent from executing jobs if the resource intense job is running on it. - In other words, is it possible for 2 jenkins masters to share a lock for this common agent?

I have tried what the following article suggested:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764464/jenkins-lock-by-label`

Looks like it is working per jenkins master, and not for multiple masters sharing an agent - as I'm able to execute both of these jobs simultaneously executing `LOW-RESOURCES-JOB` on `MASTER-1` and `RESOURCE-INTENSE-JOB` on `MASTER-2`.